# How to disassemble an entire function in Windbg?

Tags: disassembly, windows, windbg, winapi

I am trying to disassemble the function `ExAcquireFastMutex` using WinDbg but it gives me only 8 rows:

```
3: kd> u nt!ExAcquireFastMutex 
nt!ExAcquireFastMutex:
fffff805`456e3820 4053            push    rbx
fffff805`456e3822 56              push    rsi
fffff805`456e3823 57              push    rdi
fffff805`456e3824 4883ec30        sub     rsp,30h
fffff805`456e3828 33f6            xor     esi,esi
fffff805`456e382a 488bf9          mov     rdi,rcx
fffff805`456e382d 89742458        mov     dword ptr [rsp+58h],esi
fffff805`456e3831 65488b1c2588010000 mov   rbx,qword ptr gs:[188h]
```

How can I get more rows, until the return instruction ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

uf foo!blah unassemble full function